# How to autoplay ogg stream at startup of device

Tags: audio, debian, gnuradio, audio-playback

I am programming a Rasberry to Pi to become a radio player. It is meant to be used to play the [local college radio](http://radiocampus.se/) in the student union hangout.

INPUT: Power is turn on.

OUTPUT: Audio is played through the 3,5 mm jack.

PROCESS: 1) Device boot Raspdebian 2) ... 3) Start playing an ogg stream (/radiocampus_local.m3u)

How can I do this?

Comment: you have tried something already? my approach would be to write a small script (bash,perl,python) which is able to start the stream playing. if this is done you can invoke your script after boot. i described how to do it with a jar file here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13034/executing-a-jar-file-when-raspberry-boots-up/13040#13040

Answer (score 1):

OK. You can do this by adding a few commands to /etc/rc.local:

```
amixer cset numid=3 1 # force audio through the headphone jack
ogg123 -@ /home/pi/radiocampus_local.m3u # start playing music!
```

You may also need to edit /boot/config.txt so that hdmi_drive=0 to ensure audio comes out the 3.5 mm jack.

This assumes that your network is configured correctly, of course.

Comment: I forgot, if ogg123 isn't installed, it can be installed by running "sudo apt-get install vorbis-tools".

Comment: You could also add a loop + sleep to make it restart, in case the network connection is unstable